# Using another list in an Entity Framework query

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

Looking to achieve the below but it is failing as the `locations.Any()` is being treated as an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IQueryable` and scalar functions invoked via EF require `IQueryable`. I need this filter to happen at the database level (not materialize the list first).

How can I get the `locations.Any()` to be treated as an `IQueryable` here? I understand the list doesn't exist in the database but is there a way for Entity Framework to understand this any and build and `AND` statement with nested `OR` in SQL?

```
public Address GetAddresses(List<Loctions> locations)
{
   _context.Addresses.
      Where(a => locations.Any(l => MyContext.CustomFunction(l.PropA,l.PropB,  a.PropA, a.ProbB) > 1 ))
}
```

```
[DbFunction("fn_DistanceBetweenCoordinates", "dbo")]
public static decimal CustomFunction(decimal SourceLatitude, decimal SourceLongitude, decimal TargetLatitude, decimal TargetLongitude) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: How about `_context.Addresses.AsEnumerable().Where(a => locations.Any(l => MyContext.CustomFunction(l.PropA, a.PropB) > 1 ))`

Comment: This is loading all the Addresses to the memory, so it would not be an efficient query.

Comment: Are you using the classic, full Entity Framework - or Entity Framework Core? YOu have both tags - not clear which it really is ....

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work but have you tried selecting `PropA` and `PropB` into a list of tuples and then using this list in the query instead of using `locations` directly? I haven't tested it but I could imagine that this could work...

Comment: Did you try `a => locations.AsQueryable().Any(...)`?

Comment: Can you post the code of `CustomFunction`

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Yes I did, it didn't change the outcome

Comment: @marc_s ef core, but DbFunctions functionality is similar in both from what I have seen

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by moving CustomFunction into the database and use that server side function when querying from EF.

Please read [User defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) and try to adapt the sample according to your use case.

We haven't seen the body of the CustomFunction, so it's impossible to tell if it's viable to do the transfer from client based UDF to server based.

We also don't know how the Locations list is populated. Depending on how that is done, the adaptation of the example code might become more cumbersome.

Comment: Added CustomFunction to post